# USB Stick appears as Disk

Tags: hard-drive, usb

I've tried to create an bootable USB stick from a .raw file with Win32DiskImager. So far so bad, this program formatted 2 of my USB sticks as "Disk"s as seen on the captured [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iydO.png).

[image: pic]

If I try to "mount" them via *right click on "Disk 1"* > *Change Drive Letter and Paths* my PC shows me the Error "The Operation failed to complete..." (please have a look on my screenshot)

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind formatting them totally (down to the MBR), then run this:

Cmd >> DiskPart >> List Disk >> (Find the disk with the capacity of your USB drive) >> Select Disk [number from the List before] >> Clean

That would wipe the MBR of the selected drive, so be careful and choose the right one.